# How does Amazon choose first party skills for Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Amazon refers to skills created by developers as "Third Party Skills". From what I understand there are also "First Party Skills' that don't require a specific invocation name but are built in. Spotify is an example, you can ask your Alexa to play music and it can use Spotify. I have been unable to find any documentation on first part skills or lists of first party skills does anyone have a list or any experience with how to partner or create first party skills?

Comment: How is this a specific programming related question? It's at best a request for off-site resources, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you refer to first party skills you are discussing built-in functionality, common things like localized time, weather, ect., as well as partnered up skills. Here is an article from 12/17 https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/12/guidemaster-everything-amazons-alexa-can-do-plus-the-best-skills-to-enable/ certainly not complete, however it is a list.

As far as how you would develop first party skills, either get a position on the Alexa development team or work for a global large company that can provide Alexa an additional native skill that it doesn't currently possess. My guess would be the more sure way is working for Amazon.

Now what you didn't ask about is the ability to develop a third party skill and in the absence of a built-in way to respond to a users request, Amazon has created CanFulfillIntents which will provide your provided responses without the user having to envoke your skill. documentation here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-types-reference.html